# How can I reach data inside a foreach loop xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the value from a string in my Model (the HTTPClient fetches all the data and it's showed in the app). However, I need to reach the values inside the foreach loop.

This is my method in the viewmodel:

```
public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        var DataAsync = await _todoService.GetData(doItem.id, "4000");

        try
        {
            var doPin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(lats, lons),
                Label = Title,
            };

            Map.Pins.Add(doPin);

            Map.PinClicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                IsPinVisible = true;

                NewAddress = Address + todoItem?.dist;

            };
            Map.MapClicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                IsPinVisible = false;
            };               

            foreach (var i in parkDataAsync)
            {
                var todoPin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(i.lat, i.lon),
                    Label = i.name
                };

                Map.Pins.Add(todoPin);


                Map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(eventlat, eventlon), Distance.FromKilometers(1)));

            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", err);
        }
    }
```

This is the properly from where I get the value (also in the viewmodel):

```
private TodoItem _todoItem;
    public TodoItem todoItem
    {
        get => _todoItem;
        set
        {
            _todoItem = value;
            NewAddress = value.dist;
        }
    }
```

This is the string that is giving the issues:

```
NewAddress = Address + _parkItem?.dist;
```

`_parkItem?.dist` is null for some reason. The data is fetched before so I don't understand why it's null.

I also tried some other ways in order to get the `i` value from the:

```
foreach (var i in parkDataAsync)
```

I've tried stuff like this without any luck:

```
//NewAddress = Address;// + ___parkItem.Add(parktItem.dist);// parkDataAsync.Add(parktItem.dist);
```

Comment: Your string would be `null` because you either declare and initialize as `null` or you have only declared the variable and not ever set its value. You also have all of it in a `try-catch`. Are you expecting this to hit an error? If not, then do not wrap in `try-catch` as it will suppress your errors. And while you have it printing the errors that hit, it does not give you line where the error is being thrown.

Comment: Errors in code? var DataAsync = await ... are you sure? who is parkDataAsync? From where it comes from?

Comment: var DataAsync = await _todoService.GetData(doItem.id, "4000"); That is my call from the RestService.cs Page. @CalinVlasin

Comment: I declared by doing this but still null. private TodoItem _todoItem;
        public TodoItem todoItem
        {
            get => _todoItem;
            set
            {
                _todoItem = value;
                NewAddress = value.dist;
            }
        } @Symon

Comment: where do you set the value of todoItem?

Comment: Probably have not done that. Not sure what you mean but do you mean declare in the constructor? @Jason

Comment: if you do not set the value of todoItem, then it will be null.  It will not magically set its own value.

Comment: Like this: TodoItem _todoItem; public TodoItem todoItem { get => _todoItem; set { _todoItem = value; NewAddress = value.dist; } } ? @Jason

Comment: that is declaring a property, not setting its value.  setting it's value would be "todoItem = someobject;"

Comment: Ok, that will also be done in the same function as where I set the property? @Jason

Comment: I have no idea.  I'm not the person designing this app.